# Simple stored procedure-like function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1

I want to create a function in pgsql that will take three parameters and return a single value (1 row, 1 col).

I have the query working but can not seem to find a proper example of creating a function to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the example on [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html),  or [this one](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html).

If you actually go through the documentation there are multiple example of various functions and return types.

Comment: No idea why I couldn't find that. Thank you.